# Получение названия улицы из json ответа api яндекс геокодер

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api, yandex-geocoding-api

Отправляю в геокодер набор адресов Москвы и Московской области для получения улицы, координат объекта и потом, района. Ответ выглядит так:

```
  {'response': {'GeoObjectCollection': {'metaDataProperty': {'GeocoderResponseMetaData': {'request': 'город Москва, улица Егора Абакумова, дом 9',
       'results': '10',
       'found': '1'}},
     'featureMember': [{'GeoObject': {'metaDataProperty': {'GeocoderMetaData': {'precision': 'exact',
          'text': 'Россия, Москва, улица Егора Абакумова, 9',
          'kind': 'house',
          'Address': {'country_code': 'RU',
           'formatted': 'Россия, Москва, улица Егора Абакумова, 9',
           'postal_code': '129347',
           'Components': [{'kind': 'country', 'name': 'Россия'},
            {'kind': 'province', 'name': 'Центральный федеральный округ'},
            {'kind': 'province', 'name': 'Москва'},
            {'kind': 'locality', 'name': 'Москва'},
            {'kind': 'street', 'name': 'улица Егора Абакумова'},
            {'kind': 'house', 'name': '9'}]},
          'AddressDetails': {'Country': {'AddressLine': 'Россия, Москва, улица Егора Абакумова, 9',
            'CountryNameCode': 'RU',
            'CountryName': 'Россия',
            'AdministrativeArea': {'AdministrativeAreaName': 'Москва',
             'Locality': {'LocalityName': 'Москва',
              'Thoroughfare': {'ThoroughfareName': 'улица Егора Абакумова',
               'Premise': {'PremiseNumber': '9',
                'PostalCode': {'PostalCodeNumber': '129347'}}}}}}}}},
        'name': 'улица Егора Абакумова, 9',
        'description': 'Москва, Россия',
        'boundedBy': {'Envelope': {'lowerCorner': '37.710368 55.876698',
          'upperCorner': '37.718579 55.881313'}},
        'Point': {'pos': '37.714474 55.879005'}}}]}}}
```

В случае с Москвой получаю улицы таким запросом:
`response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderMetaData']['AddressDetails']['Country']['AdministrativeArea']['Locality']['Thoroughfare']['ThoroughfareName']` ,
но если в адресе больше полей, и это город в МО, то ответ выглядит так:

```
  {'response': {'GeoObjectCollection': {'metaDataProperty': {'GeocoderResponseMetaData': {'request': 'город Москва, город Щербинка, Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр, владение 8, строение 1',
       'results': '10',
       'found': '1'}},
     'featureMember': [{'GeoObject': {'metaDataProperty': {'GeocoderMetaData': {'precision': 'number',
          'text': 'Россия, Москва, Щербинка, Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр, 8А',
          'kind': 'house',
          'Address': {'country_code': 'RU',
           'formatted': 'Россия, Москва, Щербинка, Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр, 8А',
           'Components': [{'kind': 'country', 'name': 'Россия'},
            {'kind': 'province', 'name': 'Центральный федеральный округ'},
            {'kind': 'province', 'name': 'Москва'},
            {'kind': 'area', 'name': 'Новомосковский административный округ'},
            {'kind': 'area', 'name': 'поселение Щербинка'},
            {'kind': 'locality', 'name': 'Щербинка'},
            {'kind': 'street', 'name': 'Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр'},
            {'kind': 'house', 'name': '8А'}]},
          'AddressDetails': {'Country': {'AddressLine': 'Россия, Москва, Щербинка, Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр, 8А',
            'CountryNameCode': 'RU',
            'CountryName': 'Россия',
            'AdministrativeArea': {'AdministrativeAreaName': 'Москва',
             'SubAdministrativeArea': {'SubAdministrativeAreaName': 'Новомосковский административный округ',
              'Locality': {'LocalityName': 'Щербинка',
               'Thoroughfare': {'ThoroughfareName': 'Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр',
                'Premise': {'PremiseNumber': '8А'}}}}}}}}},
        'name': 'Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр, 8А',
        'description': 'Щербинка, Москва, Россия',
        'boundedBy': {'Envelope': {'lowerCorner': '37.570797 55.508473',
          'upperCorner': '37.579008 55.513132'}},
        'Point': {'pos': '37.574902 55.510803'}}}]}}}
```

и улицу получается в этом случае выделить только так:

```
  response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderMetaData']['Address']['Components'][6]
```

а хочется выделить ее по названию тэга `'kind': 'street', 'name'`, чтобы в итоге получить только название улицы в любом типе населенного пункта.

Answer (score 0):

Конечно не понятно почему Вам не устраивает тот же вариант что и в первом случае но все же можно попробовать так, чтоб без 6ки в индексе

```
 response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderMetaData']['Address']['Components'].filter(item => item.kind === 'street')[0]['name']
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: потому что в первом случае - когда мы запрашиваем для адреса в моск. области получаем следующую ошибку: 
`KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-d89e922debc2> in <module>
----> 1 response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderMetaData']['AddressDetails']['Country']['AdministrativeArea']['Locality']['Thoroughfare']['ThoroughfareName']
      2 #response = r.get(url_formatted_district).json()
      3 #response

KeyError: 'Locality'`

Comment: Предложенный вариант тоже выдает ошибку: `invalid syntax`. Хотя `response['response']['GeoObjectCollection']['featureMember'][0]['GeoObject']['metaDataProperty']['GeocoderMetaData']['Address']['Components']` выдает : `[{'kind': 'country', 'name': 'Россия'},
 {'kind': 'province', 'name': 'Центральный федеральный округ'},
 {'kind': 'province', 'name': 'Москва'},
 {'kind': 'area', 'name': 'Новомосковский АО},
 {'kind': 'area', 'name': 'пос Щербинка'},
 {'kind': 'locality', 'name': 'xx'},
 {'kind': 'street', 'name': 'Вxxx'},
 {'kind': 'house', 'name': 'xx'}]`

Comment: добавил скрин у меня всё норм

Comment: а на каком языке/в какой среде этот запрос? Мне бы на питоне. Все еще не понимаю как реализовать то что хочу...

Comment: JavaScript в браузере, тупо бросил в дебаг