# Выделить часть строки по ключевым словам

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, парсер, pandas

Есть [таблица](https://op.mos.ru/EHDWSREST/catalog/export/get?id=788383) с перечнем адресов заведений общепита, из которой нужно получить только название улицы. Адреса бывают такие:

```
город Москва, Лесная улица, дом 20, строение 1
город Москва, поселение Московский, деревня Лапшинка, владение 8, корпус 1
город Москва, город Щербинка, Варшавское шоссе, 28-й километр, владение 8, строение 1
город Москва, город Московский, улица Хабарова, дом 2
город Москва, поселение Марушкинское, деревня Марушкино, Полевая улица, дом 16
город Москва, город Зеленоград, корпус 1805
город Москва, Зеленоградская улица, дом 11
город Москва, город Зеленоград, Никольский проезд, дом 5
город Москва, город Зеленоград, Яблоневая аллея, дом 2
город Москва, город Зеленоград, проезд № 4922, дом 4, строение 5
город Москва, поселение Вороновское, посёлок ЛМС, микрорайон "Центральный", дом 34, строение 1
город Москва, 80-й километр Московской Кольцевой Автодороги, дом 4, строение 1
город Москва, проектируемый проезд № 4062, дом 6, строение 16
город Москва, город Зеленоград, проезд № 4801, дом 3, строение 1
город Москва, Проектируемый проезд N 5231, дом 8, строение 3
```

Как лучше выделить только улицу? Есть такой код, он работает в простых случаях, но не работает в большинстве примеров выше:

```
    pattern = '\,*,(([а-яА-Я1-9\-ё\s"]+)?(улица|переулок|шоссе|проспект|площадь|проезд|село|Проезд|аллея|бульвар|набережная|тупик|линия|)([а-яА-Яё1-9\-\s"]+)?)\,'
df['street'] = df['address'].str.extract(pat = pattern)[0]
```

Возвращает, например, `поселение Московский` или `город Московский`, а нужно `улица Хабарова`.

Пробовал через api яндекс геокодера, но там аналогичные сложности, описанные в вопросе [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1142328/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B8%D0%B7-json-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-api-%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80).

Comment: возможноли построчно сделать сплит по запятой, в списке пробежать по значениям содержитсяли улица,переулок и тд. ? или это плохое решение ?

Comment: я долго парился с геокодером, и теперь понимаю, что уже любое решение, если оно работает -- хорошее. Пока для вложенных городов я отбросил Москву, и выделил те объекты, где не встречается известные типы улиц. Но все равно интересно есть ли более простой вариант с регулярками.

Comment: Какая должна быть улица у адреса `город Зеленоград, корпус 1805` ?

Comment: в этом случае нет улицы, и таких вариантов около 350 среди 15000. Регулярка выше ставит NaN в таких строках. или можно избавиться от них вот так `df = df[~df['address'].str.contains('улица|переулок|шоссе|проспект|площадь|проезд|село|Проезд|аллея|бульвар|набережная|тупик|линия|километр')]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
words = ['улица','ул','переулок','шоссе','проспект','площадь','проезд',
         'село','аллея','бульвар','набережная','тупик','линия']

str_pat = r".*,\s*\b([^,]*?(?:{})\b[^,]*)[,$]+".format("|".join(words))

df["street"] = df["addr"].str.extract(str_pat, flags=re.I)
```

---

результат:

```
In [62]: df["street"]
Out[62]:
0             Лесная улица
1                      NaN
2         Варшавское шоссе
3           улица Хабарова
4            Полевая улица
5                      NaN
6     Зеленоградская улица
7        Никольский проезд
8          Яблоневая аллея
9            проезд № 4922
10                     NaN
11                     NaN
Name: street, dtype: object
```